# Oracle Listener mess

Tags: oracle, listener

Being a newbie with Oracle 12c I messed up the network setup while modifying the memory_target setting, weird I know but it happened somehow.

The SID=oradb2 up to today listened on 1538 of host oracle12c.mydomain.com nicely. Now it does not. And I don't know how port 1539 came into the picture. I hope you can help me.

Here is my $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora file:

```
LISTENER1 =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle12c.mydomain.com)(PORT = 1538))
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle12c.mydomain.com)(PORT = 1539))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Here is my $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora file

```
ORADB2 = 
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle12c.omilia.com)(PORT = 1539))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = oradb2))
  )
LISTENER_ORADB2 = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle12c.omilia.com)(PORT = 1538))
LISTENER_ORADB1 = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle12c.omilia.com)(PORT = 1538))
```

Now contacting the oradb2 SID via JDBC on port 1539 gives me ORA-12505 error, and port 1538 is not even listening.

`tnsping oradb2` gives

```
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle12c.mydomain.com)(PORT = 1539)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = oradb2)))
OK (10 msec)
```

The `/home/oracle/app/oracle/admin/oradb2/scripts/init.ora` file contains the line

```
local_listener=ORADB2
```

Comment: Copy-paste mistake, here is tnsnames.ora:
ORADB2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle12c.omilia.com)(PORT = 1539))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = oradb2)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ORADB2 =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle12c.omilia.com)(PORT = 1538))


LISTENER_ORADB1 =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle12c.omilia.com)(PORT = 1538))

Answer (score 1):

Add  a `(SID = oradb2)` to your `CONNECT_DATA` block in your `ORADB2` tns entry:

Your LISTENER entry should look like this:

```
ORADB2 =
    (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
           (ADDRESS = 
              (PROTOCOL = TCP)
              (HOST = oracle12c.mydomain.com)
              (PORT = 1539)
            )
         )
      )
      (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SID = oradb2)
      )
    )
```

And then in TNSNAMES.ORA put this:

```
ORADB2 = 
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = 
       (PROTOCOL = TCP)
       (HOST = oracle12c.omilia.com)
       (PORT = 1539)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
       (SID = oradb2)
    )
  )
```

You can make the port whatever you want from here. Just make sure you make it the same in both the listener and the tnsnames entry.

Comment: Thank you! Initially your suggestion didn't work, port 1539 was not opened, but 1521 was, so I changed all to 1521 and it worked, so I'm grateful to you. Please advise on what is missing so that I can also have EM run on 5500. I have looked in Oracle docs but this topic is not clear at all, at least for an untrained beginner. It should and could be simpler than it is.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this. You should post this as a new question. That aside, have you installed management agent?

Comment: The EM was working initially, so I'm sure it's installed, it's only a matter of config to fix it. I have yet to find an Oracle doc that explains how the listener needs to be set up in order to support EM.